# How to make firefly docker container locally reachable using subdirs with traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

After reading many tutorials and the official documentation, after trying to make it work by myself during 4 days, I decided to ask for your help.
I'm a beginner with docker and traefik, I'm surely doing something wrong but I can't figure what.

Currently I would like to host Firefly-III behind traefik in order to access it locally without https and if it works, I will like to access it remotely. The purpose of traefik is that if I succeed accessing it, I would like to host other services.
Here are my configuration files but, resulting in a 404 error.

**docker-compose.yml :**

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  traefik:
  firefly:

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:latest"
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    networks:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  firefly:
    image: fireflyiii/core:latest
    container_name: firefly
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.firefly.rule=Host(`localhost`) && Path(`/firefly`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.firefly.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.firefly.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik
      - firefly
    volumes:
      - firefly_iii_upload:/var/www/html/storage/upload
    env_file: firefly.env
    depends_on:
      - fireflydb
    ports:
      - 80

  fireflydb:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: fireflydb
    restart: always
    networks:
      - firefly
    env_file: fireflydb.env
    volumes:
      - firefly_iii_db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  firefly_iii_upload:
  firefly_iii_db:
```

**firefly.env :**

```
# You can leave this on "local". If you change it to production most console commands will ask for extra confirmation.
# Never set it to "testing".
APP_ENV=local

# Set to true if you want to see debug information in error screens.
APP_DEBUG=false

# This should be your email address.
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set this variable from a file by using SITE_OWNER_FILE
SITE_OWNER=me@example.org

# The encryption key for your sessions. Keep this very secure.
# Change it to a string of exactly 32 chars or use something like `php artisan key:generate` to generate it.
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set this variable from a file by using APP_KEY_FILE
APP_KEY=My32charsappkey

# Firefly III will launch using this language (for new users and unauthenticated visitors)
# For a list of available languages: https://github.com/firefly-iii/firefly-iii/tree/main/resources/lang
#
# If text is still in English, remember that not everything may have been translated.
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=fr_FR

# The locale defines how numbers are formatted.
# by default this value is the same as whatever the language is.
DEFAULT_LOCALE=equal

# Change this value to your preferred time zone.
# Example: Europe/Amsterdam
# For a list of supported time zones, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
TZ=Pacific/Tahiti

# TRUSTED_PROXIES is a useful variable when using Docker and/or a reverse proxy.
# Set it to ** and reverse proxies work just fine.
TRUSTED_PROXIES=**

# The log channel defines where your log entries go to.
# Several other options exist. You can use 'single' for one big fat error log (not recommended).
# Also available are 'syslog', 'errorlog' and 'stdout' which will log to the system itself.
# A rotating log option is 'daily', creates 5 files that (surprise) rotate.
# A cool option is 'papertrail' for cloud logging
# Default setting 'stack' will log to 'daily' and to 'stdout' at the same time.
LOG_CHANNEL=stack

#
# Used when logging to papertrail:
#
PAPERTRAIL_HOST=
PAPERTRAIL_PORT=

# Log level. You can set this from least severe to most severe:
# debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert, emergency
# If you set it to debug your logs will grow large, and fast. If you set it to emergency probably
# nothing will get logged, ever.
APP_LOG_LEVEL=notice

# Audit log level.
# Set this to "emergency" if you dont want to store audit logs, leave on info otherwise.
AUDIT_LOG_LEVEL=info

# Database credentials. Make sure the database exists. I recommend a dedicated user for Firefly III
# For other database types, please see the FAQ: https://docs.firefly-iii.org/support/faq
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set these variables from a file by appending them with _FILE
# Use "pgsql" for PostgreSQL
# Use "mysql" for MySQL and MariaDB.
# Use "sqlite" for SQLite.
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=firefly
DB_USERNAME=firefly
DB_PASSWORD=superpasswordhere
# leave empty or omit when not using a socket connection
DB_SOCKET=

# MySQL supports SSL. You can configure it here.
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set these variables from a file by appending them with _FILE
MYSQL_USE_SSL=false
MYSQL_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT=true
# You need to set at least of these options
MYSQL_SSL_CAPATH=/etc/ssl/certs/
MYSQL_SSL_CA=
MYSQL_SSL_CERT=
MYSQL_SSL_KEY=
MYSQL_SSL_CIPHER=

# PostgreSQL supports SSL. You can configure it here.
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set these variables from a file by appending them with _FILE
PGSQL_SSL_MODE=prefer
PGSQL_SSL_ROOT_CERT=null
PGSQL_SSL_CERT=null
PGSQL_SSL_KEY=null
PGSQL_SSL_CRL_FILE=null

# more PostgreSQL settings
PGSQL_SCHEMA=public

# If you're looking for performance improvements, you could install memcached or redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file

# If you set either of the options above to 'redis', you might want to update these settings too
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set REDIS_HOST_FILE, REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE or
# REDIS_PORT_FILE to set the value from a file instead of from an environment variable

# can be tcp, unix or http
REDIS_SCHEME=tcp

# use only when using 'unix' for REDIS_SCHEME. Leave empty otherwise.
REDIS_PATH=

# use only when using 'tcp' or 'http' for REDIS_SCHEME. Leave empty otherwise.
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT=6379

# Use only with Redis 6+ with proper ACL set. Leave empty otherwise.
REDIS_USERNAME=
REDIS_PASSWORD=

# always use quotes and make sure redis db "0" and "1" exists. Otherwise change accordingly.
REDIS_DB="0"
REDIS_CACHE_DB="1"

# Cookie settings. Should not be necessary to change these.
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set COOKIE_DOMAIN_FILE to set
# the value from a file instead of from an environment variable
# Setting samesite to "strict" may give you trouble logging in.
COOKIE_PATH="/"
COOKIE_DOMAIN=
COOKIE_SECURE=false
COOKIE_SAMESITE=lax

# If you want Firefly III to email you, update these settings
# For instructions, see: https://docs.firefly-iii.org/advanced-installation/email
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set these variables from a file by appending them with _FILE
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.example.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM=me@example.org
MAIL_USERNAME=me@example.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=nicepasswordbro
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

# Other mail drivers:
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set these variables from a file by appending them with _FILE
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=
MAILGUN_SECRET=

# If you are on EU region in mailgun, use api.eu.mailgun.net, otherwise use api.mailgun.net
# If you use Docker or similar, you can set this variable from a file by appending it with _FILE
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.mailgun.net

# If you use Docker or similar, you can set these variables from a file by appending them with _FILE
MANDRILL_SECRET=
SPARKPOST_SECRET=

# Firefly III can send you the following messages.
SEND_REGISTRATION_MAIL=true
SEND_ERROR_MESSAGE=true
SEND_LOGIN_NEW_IP_WARNING=true

# These messages contain (sensitive) transaction information:
SEND_REPORT_JOURNALS=true

# Set this value to true if you want to set the location
# of certain things, like transactions. Since this involves an external service, it's optional
# and disabled by default.
ENABLE_EXTERNAL_MAP=false

# The map will default to this location:
MAP_DEFAULT_LAT=-17.68333
MAP_DEFAULT_LONG=-149.58333
MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM=6

#
# Firefly III authentication settings
#

#
# Firefly III supports a few authentication methods:
# - 'web' (default, uses built in DB)
# - 'remote_user_guard' for Authelia etc
# Read more about these settings in the documentation.
# https://docs.firefly-iii.org/advanced-installation/authentication
#
# LDAP is no longer supported :(
#
AUTHENTICATION_GUARD=web

#
# Remote user guard settings
#
AUTHENTICATION_GUARD_HEADER=REMOTE_USER
AUTHENTICATION_GUARD_EMAIL=

#
# Extra authentication settings
#
CUSTOM_LOGOUT_URL=

# You can disable the X-Frame-Options header if it interferes with tools like
# Organizr. This is at your own risk. Applications running in frames run the risk
# of leaking information to their parent frame.
DISABLE_FRAME_HEADER=false

# You can disable the Content Security Policy header when you're using an ancient browser
# or any version of Microsoft Edge / Internet Explorer (which amounts to the same thing really)
# This leaves you with the risk of not being able to stop XSS bugs should they ever surface.
# This is at your own risk.
DISABLE_CSP_HEADER=false

# If you wish to track your own behavior over Firefly III, set valid analytics tracker information here.
# Nobody uses this except for me on the demo site. But hey, feel free to use this if you want to.
# Do not prepend the TRACKER_URL with http:// or https://
# The only tracker supported is Matomo.
# You can set the following variables from a file by appending them with _FILE:
TRACKER_SITE_ID=
TRACKER_URL=

#
# Firefly III supports webhooks. These are security sensitive and must be enabled manually first.
#
ALLOW_WEBHOOKS=false

#
# The static cron job token can be useful when you use Docker and wish to manage cron jobs.
# 1. Set this token to any 32-character value (this is important!).
# 2. Use this token in the cron URL instead of a user's command line token.
#
# For more info: https://docs.firefly-iii.org/firefly-iii/advanced-installation/cron/
#
# You can set this variable from a file by appending it with _FILE
#
STATIC_CRON_TOKEN=

# You can fine tune the start-up of a Docker container by editing these environment variables.
# Use this at your own risk. Disabling certain checks and features may result in lost of inconsistent data.
# However if you know what you're doing you can significantly speed up container start times.
# Set each value to true to enable, or false to disable.

# Set this to true to build all locales supported by Firefly III.
# This may take quite some time (several minutes) and is generally not recommended.
# If you wish to change or alter the list of locales, start your Docker container with
# `docker run -v locale.gen:/etc/locale.gen -e DKR_BUILD_LOCALE=true`
# and make sure your preferred locales are in your own locale.gen.
DKR_BUILD_LOCALE=false

# Check if the SQLite database exists. Can be skipped if you're not using SQLite.
# Won't significantly speed up things.
DKR_CHECK_SQLITE=true

# Run database creation and migration commands. Disable this only if you're 100% sure the DB exists
# and is up to date.
DKR_RUN_MIGRATION=true

# Run database upgrade commands. Disable this only when you're 100% sure your DB is up-to-date
# with the latest fixes (outside of migrations!)
DKR_RUN_UPGRADE=true

# Verify database integrity. Includes all data checks and verifications.
# Disabling this makes Firefly III assume your DB is intact.
DKR_RUN_VERIFY=true

# Run database reporting commands. When disabled, Firefly III won't go over your data to report current state.
# Disabling this should have no impact on data integrity or safety but it won't warn you of possible issues.
DKR_RUN_REPORT=true

# Generate OAuth2 keys.
# When disabled, Firefly III won't attempt to generate OAuth2 Passport keys. This won't be an issue, IFF (if and only if)
# you had previously generated keys already and they're stored in your database for restoration.
DKR_RUN_PASSPORT_INSTALL=true

# Leave the following configuration vars as is.
# Unless you like to tinker and know what you're doing.
APP_NAME=FireflyIII
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
CACHE_PREFIX=firefly
PUSHER_KEY=
IPINFO_TOKEN=
PUSHER_SECRET=
PUSHER_ID=
DEMO_USERNAME=
DEMO_PASSWORD=
IS_HEROKU=false
FIREFLY_III_LAYOUT=v1

#
# If you have trouble configuring your Firefly III installation, DON'T BOTHER setting this variable.
# It won't work. It doesn't do ANYTHING. Don't believe the lies you read online. I'm not joking.
# This configuration value WILL NOT HELP.
#
# Notable exception to this rule is Synology, which, according to some users, will use APP_URL to rewrite stuff.
#
# This variable is ONLY used in some of the emails Firefly III sends around. Nowhere else.
# So when configuring anything WEB related this variable doesn't do anything. Nothing
#
# If you're stuck I understand you get desperate but look SOMEWHERE ELSE.
#
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad right now. There's a lot of material here, and it's not immediately clear exactly what you're having problems with. Can you reduce this to a single fundamental problem? For example, if you have questions about Traefik configuration ditch all the details about fidi and firefly and grocy and just use dummy containers running nginx or something and focus your question on how to correctly configure traefik. Once you have *that* working, then try moving to the next step.

Comment: Thank for the comment larsks and for the way to follow. I'll try to limit the question to something like "how to run firefly with traefik reverse proxy" and remove parts out of scope.